# C# - Preventing from writing append lines in file if file is exist

Tags: c#, file, stream, filestream

Help!! How can i make a program that stops the program from append a new line in an existed file?

Code:

```
   if (File.Exists(path)) 
        {

        }
        FileStream fs = null;
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (fs = File.Create(path))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Text File Created Succesfully!");
            }
        }
        string[] OrigProductItems = { "Blood Pressure Monitor\t", "Digital Scale\t\t", "Footrest\t\t", "Health Care Thermometers", "Massager\t\t" };
        int[] OrigProductQty = {30, 10, 5, 20, 10};
        double[] OrigProductPrice = { 799.75, 499.75, 99.95, 79.75, 1990.75 };


        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                for (ctrl = 0; ctrl < 5 ; ctrl++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(OrigProductItems[ctrl] + "\t" + OrigProductQty[ctrl] + "\t\t" + OrigProductPrice[ctrl]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe check and return? `if (File.Exists(path)) return;`

Comment: Is this your code that you can control what it does?  Or is it some other code you don't control so you can't change the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just negate what you already have

```
    if (!File.Exists(path)) // append only if file doesnt exist
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            for (ctrl = 0; ctrl < 5 ; ctrl++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(OrigProductItems[ctrl] + "\t" + OrigProductQty[ctrl] + "\t\t" + OrigProductPrice[ctrl]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!